# gRPC unauthenticated exception caused by method not foudn

Tags: java, spring-boot, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

I have a C++ client calling my Java gRPC server, and get the following exception when trying to call a method - clearly listed in my proto file.

`org.lognet.springboot.grpc.GRpcServicesRegistry#descriptorToServiceMethod` doesn't map the RPC methods, of the form `rpc_method_name` (snake-case) to the generated java methods, of the form `rpcMethodName` (camel-case).

This causes the following error to be thrown at run-time:

```
org.lognet.springboot.grpc.security.SecurityInterceptor$1: Authentication failure.
    at org.lognet.springboot.grpc.security.SecurityInterceptor.interceptCall(SecurityInterceptor.java:147) ~[grpc-spring-boot-starter-4.5.10.jar:na]
    at io.grpc.ServerInterceptors$InterceptCallHandler.startCall(ServerInterceptors.java:244) ~[grpc-api-1.42.0.jar:1.42.0]
    at org.lognet.springboot.grpc.recovery.GRpcExceptionHandlerInterceptor.interceptCall(GRpcExceptionHandlerInterceptor.java:59) ~[grpc-spring-boot-starter-4.5.10.jar:na]
    at io.grpc.ServerInterceptors$InterceptCallHandler.startCall(ServerInterceptors.java:244) ~[grpc-api-1.42.0.jar:1.42.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl.startWrappedCall(ServerImpl.java:703) ~[grpc-core-1.42.0.jar:1.42.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl.access$2200(ServerImpl.java:406) ~[grpc-core-1.42.0.jar:1.42.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl$1HandleServerCall.runInternal(ServerImpl.java:615) ~[grpc-core-1.42.0.jar:1.42.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl$1HandleServerCall.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:603) ~[grpc-core-1.42.0.jar:1.42.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) ~[grpc-core-1.42.0.jar:1.42.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133) ~[grpc-core-1.42.0.jar:1.42.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method ***rpc_method_name*** not found in service ***org.me.MyGrpcService***
    at org.lognet.springboot.grpc.GRpcServicesRegistry.descriptorToServiceMethod(GRpcServicesRegistry.java:186) ~[grpc-spring-boot-starter-4.5.10.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.util.function.SingletonSupplier.get(SingletonSupplier.java:97) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.lognet.springboot.grpc.GRpcServicesRegistry.getGrpServiceMethod(GRpcServicesRegistry.java:120) ~[grpc-spring-boot-starter-4.5.10.jar:na]
    at org.lognet.springboot.grpc.security.SecurityInterceptor.setupGRpcSecurityContext(SecurityInterceptor.java:261) ~[grpc-spring-boot-starter-4.5.10.jar:na]
    at org.lognet.springboot.grpc.security.SecurityInterceptor.interceptCall(SecurityInterceptor.java:143) ~[grpc-spring-boot-starter-4.5.10.jar:na]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Is this a bug with the api, or is there some config/dependency I'm missing?

Comment: I have a try for snake case service and method generate, it is snake case correctly. Please make sure your code is generated from same proto file and dependency version is same.

Comment: @HelloWood I used the lognet grpc gradle plugin to handle generation / grpc versions